# Can I use an ESP8266 as a replacement for an original Arduino?

Tags: esp8266

I want to learn Arduino, but I'd like to use the ESP8266 as it has built in wifi. I understand that I can use the Arduino IDE for this board.

However, what about books and resources out there? Are these two boards so similar that I can follow original Arduino examples? I'm primarily thinking in terms of connectivity to, say, sensors.

I'm a beginner at this and will not be able to figure out how to bridge compatibility gaps.

Comment: Neither "ESP8266" nor "Arduino" is a board.

Comment: Ah, pardon my ignorance - I should have been more specific, although I did mention that I am a beginner. Would you care to enlighten me about the right terms?

Comment: Well, no, because there are dozens of boards that use the ESP8266 microcontroller and fall under the Arduino brand. You can't just mix-and-match between them.

Comment: So when you select ESP8266 in the Arduino IDE, this only goes for a few specific boards?

Comment: No, it works with a wide range of boards that use the ESP8266, but they vary wildly with respect to the number and placement of external connections.

Comment: Which "original Arduino" do you have in mind? There are [a lot of Arduino types (boards)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Products).

Comment: Firstly, there are no ESP8266 "boards" that fall under the "Arduino brand" that I'm aware of - secondly, most common ESP8266 have 11 available GPIO's, far less than most common Arduino boards (some as few as 4) - depending on how many and what type of sensors you wish to use at any one time is a major factor in your decision making

Comment: @JaromandaX - Sorry but all ESP8266 processors have the same number of GPIO connections.  The boards that use ESP8266 processors have varying numbers of those GPIO connections taken to the edge.

Comment: In my comment. Take esp8266 to mean esp8266 board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, No and Maybe is the best answer :)

Assuming that you want to replace a Arduino Uno board with an ESP8266 **based** board.  Your best choice at the moment would be a Wemos D1.  It has the same form factor as the UNO, but it has less pins, 9 digital and 1 analog.

If you are not bothered about the form factor, you could also try a Node-LUA, or a Wemos D1 Mini.  If you have steady hands you could try just using the heart of these three boards directly, which is usually called an ESP8266-12E, but it has 1mm pitch and no voltage regulation.

There are a lot of sites around that have tutorials on using ESPs.  They are mostly interchangeable with Arduino boards from a software perspective, they have more memory and a faster clock speed.

The biggest difference between an Arduino based board and an ESP board is **most** Arduino use 5v and **most** ESP based boards use 3.3v.  Make sure you read the datasheet before you hook up you sensors.

There is an ESP-32 as well.  This is not interchangeable with an Arduino Uno at the moment.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate your answer even though my question was not all that clear. I'll be looking into the boards you've mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Are these two boards so similar that I can follow original Arduino examples?

for most applications, an mcu is useful not because of its core - which is almost fully transparent to a high level language programmer - but because of its peripherals: timers, serial comms, interrupts, adc/dac, ...

sure, there are applications that don't require those functionalities; or those functionalities could be emulated. but you will find it much easier if the mcu does have those functionalities.

so all it takes is to take a look at the datasheet of your esp and ask yourself if you see those peripherals. after that, the answer is clear.